# Bind viewmodel to recyclerview item.xml with databinding, android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding, viewmodel

I want to bind data on adapter from viewmodel in xml layout file

This is my fragment class.

```
class NotificationFragment : Fragment() {
var customeProgressDialog: CustomeProgressDialog? = null
private val appPreferences: AppPreference by inject()
private val notificationViewModel: NotificationViewModel by viewModel()
private lateinit var binding: FragmentNotificationBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentNotificationBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.getRoot()
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.notification.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    customeProgressDialog = CustomeProgressDialog(activity)
    notificationViewModel.notifications(
        appPreferences.getUsername(),
        appPreferences.getPassword(),
        appPreferences.getUserId()
    )
    initObservables()
}

private fun initObservables() {
    notificationViewModel.progressDialog?.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it!!) customeProgressDialog?.show() else customeProgressDialog?.dismiss()
    })
    notificationViewModel.apiResponse?.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        androidx.lifecycle.Observer { response ->
            if (response.dataList != null) {
                var notificationAdapter = NotificationAdapter(response.dataList as List<Data>)
                notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                binding.notification.adapter = notificationAdapter
            }
        })
}
}
```

My viewmodel

```
class NotificationViewModel(networkCall: NetworkCall) : ViewModel(),
Callback<ApiResponse> {
var progressDialog: SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>? = null
var apiResponse: MutableLiveData<ApiResponse>? = null
var networkCall: NetworkCall;
init {
    progressDialog = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()
    apiResponse = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse>()
    this.networkCall = networkCall
}

fun notifications(username: String?, password: String?, userId: String?) {
    progressDialog?.value = true
    val apiPost = ApiPost()
    apiPost.userName = username
    apiPost.password = password
    apiPost.UserId = userId
    apiPost.FileType = NetworkConstant.FILE_TYPE_NOT
    networkCall.getPDF(apiPost).enqueue(this)
}

override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
    progressDialog?.value = false
}

override fun onResponse(call: Call<ApiResponse>, response: Response<ApiResponse>) {
    progressDialog?.value = false
    apiResponse?.value = response.body()
}
}
```

The adapter class

```
lass NotificationAdapter(private val list: List<Data>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_list, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val movie: Data = list[position]
    holder.bind(movie)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(movie.filePath)) {
            try {
                val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movie.filePath))
                holder.itemView.context.startActivity(browserIntent)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(movie: Data) {
        with(itemView) {
            tv_notifi.text = movie.displayName
            tv_date.text = movie.UpdatedDate
            if (movie.description != null) {
                tv_brief.text = movie.description
                tv_brief.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

This is my item xml layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.mountmeru.viewmodel.NotificationViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/main_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/main_cardrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_newsdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_notifi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="hey i am notification text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_brief"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_notifi"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_brief"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="hey i am date"
                android:textColor="@color/inactive_text"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_newsdate"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_notifi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/mer" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

I was able to do the binding for the fragment but for adapter I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass data to your adapter inside xml. For this, you will need to write custom binding adapter for your RecyclerView. 
This link has all you need. 
https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-bind-a-list-of-items-to-a-recyclerview-with-android-data-binding-1bd08b4796b4